Does the Minimalist achievement count Exhausted cards?
The Minimalist achievement states

Beat the game with a 5 card deck or smaller.

Does this include cards that are exhausted during combat? For example, if I fight the final boss with a 10 card deck then exhaust 5 cards during combat, does that count for the Minimalist achievement?

According to Reddit, no:

Do exhaust/power cards count towards the achievement? Lets say I use 2 inflame and a random exhaust in an 8 card deck and I’m left with 5 cards. Would it count towards the achievement, or do I have to go into the battle with 5 cards?


No, it looks at the deck size at the top where it has the number

